# convert multiple files from base64 to pdf in memory

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am receiving several files in base64 format and I need to upload them to aws s3 in pdf format but so far I have tried everything and I still can't do it, is there any way to convert them to pdf without creating a file?

i'm using django rest framwork

```
      "balance":"base64String",
      "stateOfCashflow":"base64String",
      "financialStatementAudit":"base64String",
      "managementReport":"base64String",
      "certificateOfStockOwnership":"base64String",
      "rentDeclaration":"base64String",
```

Comment: in the end you are wrong at some point I found a django library that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own, I found a library called drf_extra_fields which does just what I need.

in the serializer is necesary to use base64filefield which takes the string in base 64 and transforms it into pdf behind the scenes

```
from drf_extra_fields.fields import Base64FileField
import PyPDF2
import io


class PDFBase64File(Base64FileField):
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['pdf']

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        try:
            PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(decoded_file))
        except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            return 'pdf'

class PDFSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pdf = PDFBase64File()
    class Meta:
        model = pdf
        fields = "__all__"
```